# dictionaries create table python

Tags: python

I don't get it why here the result is [[0 0] [0 0]];
Here is the code:

```
def create_table(m,n):
    t=[]
    one_line=[]
    for i in range(0,m):
        one_line.append(0)
    for i in range(0,n):
        t.append(one_line)
    return t

print(create_table(2,2));
```

After first iteration in one_line we have [0] and in t [[0]].

After the second iteration, where i=2 we have one_line = [0 0] and in t = [[0 0] [0 0]]. But why is not t=[[0] [0 0]] because the previous t was [[0]] not [[0 0] [0 0]].

Any explanation?

Comment: I don't understand it………what do you mean by "the previous t"?

Comment: one_line.append(0) every time append a 0 on list .

Comment: we have the first t from the first iteration where it was [[0]].

Comment: @IrinaFarcau Make sure the code above is what it is.

Comment: i think, you have understood python loop false. the second loop will run after the the first loop is finished. the previous t of your code was [[0, 0]] and not [[0]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined two for loops:

1. First you loop twice through the first for loop, creating one_line=[0,0]
2. Then you loop trough the second loop (twice), thus appending [0,0] twice to t thus ending up with t=[[0,0],[0,0]]

Answer (score 0):

So run your function call create_table(2, 2)

```
create_table(2, 2):
```

set: m = 2, n = 2

```
t = []
one_line = []
```

define: t = [], one_line = []

```
for i in range(0,m):
```

for i in [0, 1]

with i = 0

```
one_line.append(0)
```

one_line = [0]

with i = 1

```
one_line.append(0)
```

one_line = [0, 0]

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

for i in (0, 1)

with i = 0

```
t.append(one_line)
```

t = [[0, 0]]

with i = 1

```
t.append(one_line)
```

t = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]